# How to place updated data into specific element?

Tags: angularjs

I have listed items and it's children using ng-repeat.

```
have items = [
  {item.id:1,
   item.name :'item1',
   item.children: [
      {item.id:11,
       item.name :'child1',  
       },
       {item.id:22,
       item.name :'child2',  
       }, 
       {item.id:33,
       item.name :'child3',  
       }]  
  },
  {item.id:2,
   item.name :'item2',
   item.children: [
      {item.id:12,
       item.name :'child22',  
       },
       {item.id:23,
       item.name :'child33',  
       }, 
       {item.id:34,
       item.name :'child44',  
       }]  
  }
];

<div id = "item.id" ng-repeat="item in vm.items">
  <div>{{item.name}}</div>
  <div id = "child.id" ng-repeat="child in item.children">
    <div>{{child.name}}</div>
  </div>
```

Than when I receive updated child e.g.

```
       {item.id:34,
       item.name :'child44_renamed',  
       }
```

I want to place a child data into element where it was rendered.
is there way to do it?

Thank you for advice in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can change the structure of your `items` array object and Angular will automatically re-render the whole thing.

The easiest way to manipulate with JavaScript objects and arrays is by using a library, such as **[lodash](https://lodash.com)**.
You can also do it with plain JavaScript but using a library will save you much time and energy.

By using lodash, for example, you can find the `item` based on the `id` and `name` and then do the changes on it.

Comment: thanks. but is it possible to change array directly in html element where it was rendered?

Comment: Why you need to do it that way? Don't want to re-render?

Comment: imagine if child has also children, and it's children has also children. how to get child.array , change it and put back in that place where it was rendered?

Comment: Please check the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079541/angularjs-ng-repeat-with-dynamic-list-without-rebuilding-entire-dom-tree